# 400Mhz frequence HackRF One

Tags: power-electronics, receiver, radiation, sdr

All,

Sorry but I am new to this topic and have no experience with SDR myself.First, I briefly give the hardware that I am using:

- HackRF One
- Following antenna: https://zsecurity.org/product/atheros-ar9271-2-4-ghz-usb-wifi-wireless-adapter/

Story/question:
Yesterday I had used the software "gqrx" for the first time together with the hackrf one. The point was just to see what signals were in my area and if I could receive signals. The weird thing was there was a strong signal that went on frequancy 400 Mhz... Normally the HacRFone could go to max 6Ghz. After searching some more information on the internet, I found out that this is very bad for the health.
So now I wonder what happens when people start doing such a high frequency with the HackRF One. Beside that, should I be concerned about my health or isn't that possible to receive such a high frequency that could harm my body with such a basic setup?

Thanks in advance! I searched a lot but didn't find any good information...

Kr
[image: Picture of my screen]

Comment: *frequancy 400 Ghz* 400 GHz is a very high **frequency**, only very specialist devices work at those frequencies. A device that is designed to work up to 6 GHz isn't going to do much at 400 GHz. Very likely this signal you see at 400 GHz is an **artifact** of the software.

Comment: *After searching some more information on the internet, I found out that this is very bad for the health.* Anything is bad for your health depending on who you ask. 1) this 400 GHz very likely doesn't really exist. 2) Devices that are able to generate 400 GHz signals at **a power level that is harmful to humans** exist but are **VERY** expensive. The real danger with HackRF devices is people "seeing things" and then drawing wrong and uneducated conclusions from that.

Comment: Where in your screenshot does it say 400 **GHz**. I don't see the **GHz** anywhere in the screenshot. could it be 400 **MHz** ?

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, thank you for answer. So I can see it as a bug in the software? So I can say that I didn't receive anything harmful? Ps: Do you have advice of a good course to start with SDR?

Comment: @AJN I've got a HackRF and it displays in Hz so you're right the above is 400 Mhz.

Comment: @HereToLearn:  Right there in the middle of your screenshot it says "0400,000,000."  That's 400 MHz, not 400GHz.

Comment: @JRE Oh okay but 400 MHz could that be a signal or not? And if so, I think this is also harmful or am I wrong?

Comment: That leading zero matches the maximum range (6GHz) of the module.

Comment: So when there is no match it draws a sort of signal? And what if we do 4 400 000 000

Comment: 400MHz can easily be a radio signal. Since it **exactly** 400 MHz, it is more likely to be an artifact of the computer or monitor you are using.  The signal level appears to be -35dBm.  That's about 1/1000 of the power of the light from a firefly, if the firefly were right on your skin.  It is **not** dangerous.

Comment: @JRE thank you very much for all the information! Do you recognize a course or book to buy to get a deeper education in this?

Comment: "Matches" in the sense that there are 10 digits which would allow for frequencies up to 9,999,999,999 Hz to be displayed.  That is adequate to display the maximum 6GHz that the module can receive.

Comment: @JRE oh okay so if I understand it right, when we try to receive a higher Ghz then we could receive, it wouldn't work and will take it 6 Ghz?

Comment: No.  If the signal is higher than 6GHz, the HackRF can't even "see" it - ideally, you would see nothing from your device if there were a higher frequency signal coming in.

Comment: @JRE, Thank you so much for your information! I'm happy that it isn't dangerous and I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be harmed by receiving radio signals on an antenna unless you are extremely close to the transmitter. In any case, those signals are present at your location whether you have a receiver or not. It is also doubtful if you can receive a signal at 400 GHz if your receiver is only supposed to work up to 6 GHz. It is probably generated internally by nonlinearities in your receiver. I don't know of any commercial transmitters operating at that frequency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean the transmitter of which data is send or transmitter of my device? That's why I'm asking here, 400Ghz would be very harmful but it seems strong to me that I could receive this effectively.